# Cannot copy html formatted string to clipboard in Chrome

Tags: html, typescript, google-chrome, angular5, clipboard

I work on `angular5` and I have to copy some `HTML` code from `clipboard` and paste it in the outlook. I have achieved it this for IE but same code is not working in chrome, chrome does not copy anything at all nor showing any console errors.

Basically, as soon as I copy I have to create a `hyperlink` and past that hyperlink in the outlook and when user clicks on that link a new page with that hyperlink ref should open. My code as below, please help me achieve copy functionality for chrome?

```
public copyToClipboard {
  const body = document.createElement('body');
  const breakLine = document.createElement('br');
  const ol = document.createElement('ol');

  const range = document.createRange();
  document.body.appendChild(body);
  body.appendChild(ol);

  let name: string;
  this.selectedFiles.forEach(doc => {
    const docURL = this.serviceCall();
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    const li = document.createElement('li');

    anchor.href = docURL;
    anchor.text = doc.fileName;
    name = doc.name;
    body.appendChild(li).appendChild(anchor);
   });
    range.selectNode(body);

    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(body);
}

//HTML
<button pButton (click)="copyToClipboard()"></button>
```

(Please ignore if any spelling mistakes in my code as I have typed the code instead of copy+paste, this code is working perfect in IE)

Comment: When is it called? Also any reason for using a <body> tag? Sounds kinda asking for troubles.

Comment: I have updated question for how it is called. No specific reason to use <body>. This is what I tried the first time it worked so I did not play around the code. Any suggestions on this, should I try something else?

Comment: Well the only authorized parent for a body element is an html element. Most browser will allow you to append an other one somewhere else in the document, but you may face issues, that could not really be accounted as browser bugs. And from fast testing, it seems it is indeed your current issue (which is still quite surprising TBH). Try replacing it with a <div>  for instance.

Comment: @Kaiido I tried replacing body with div like this 'const body = document.createElement('div');' but allas still not working in chrome –

Answer (score 0):

I guess their recent implementation of the async ClipboardAPI made Chrome change their behavior w.r.t. `execCommand('copy')`, since it looks like it is now an async method.
`execCommand` is supposed to be a synchronous method, so this qualifies as a browser bug.

Now the workaround is to wait a little bit before you remove your source element.

(Also note that using a <body> element here was a bad idea and actually an other part of the issue).

```js
const obj = {
  serviceCall() { return Math.random();},
  selectedFiles: [
    { name: 'foo', fileName: 'foo.bar' },
    { name: 'bar', fileName: 'bar.foo' }
  ],
  copyToClipboard() {
    // don't use a <body> element
    const body = document.createElement('div');
    const breakLine = document.createElement('br');
    const ol = document.createElement('ol');

    const range = document.createRange();
    document.body.appendChild(body);
    body.appendChild(ol);

    let name = ""; // we're in pure js
    this.selectedFiles.forEach(doc => {
      const docURL = this.serviceCall();
      const anchor = document.createElement('a');
      const li = document.createElement('li');

      anchor.href = docURL;
      anchor.text = doc.fileName;
      name = doc.name;
      body.appendChild(li).appendChild(anchor);
    });
    range.selectNode(body);

    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    // wait just a bit
    requestAnimationFrame(() =>
      document.body.removeChild(body)
    );
  }
}

btn.onclick = e => obj.copyToClipboard();
```

```html
<button id='btn'>
  copy to clipboard
</button>
<textarea>paste here to check your clipboard's content</textarea>
```

Comment: thanks for you efforts. However, this code works fine if I copy just a string but when I want to copy the HTML (here i am forming a hyperlink) its does not work, it does not even copy. Not sure this is any browser issue or code issue. Giving some extra info I have chrome 70.0.35 and I work on angular 5.2.10 and my client machine does not have internet. Any ideas from you side?

Comment: Also, to add, when I console log the div I can see the correct HTML forming its just that it does not get copied.